# Рейтинг из звездочек. Как поправить/упростить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Решил попробовать написать рейтинг звездочек на jquery и немного запутался, ниже код в котором есть один хороший баг, если изначально 3 звезды активные, то при наведении на 4ую, она и предыдущие становятся активные, а это должно происходить только при клике, а не наведении. + мой код наверное слишком большой для такой задачи и можно всё упростить, но я увы не понимаю как.

P.S. Ответы на чистом js так же подойдут :)

```js
var cStars = function(NowPos) {
 if(NowPos.index() == 0) {
   // У всех убираем active
   $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
   for(var i = 0; 1 > i; i++) {
     $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
    }
  }
  if(NowPos.index() == 1) {
   // У всех убираем active
   $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
   for(var i = 0; 2 > i; i++) {
     $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
    }
  }
  if(NowPos.index() == 2) {
   // У всех убираем active
   $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
   for(var i = 0; 3 > i; i++) {
     $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
    }
  }
  if(NowPos.index() == 3) {
   // У всех убираем active
   $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
   for(var i = 0; 4 > i; i++) {
     $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
    }
  }
  if(NowPos.index() == 4) {
   // У всех убираем active
   $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
   for(var i = 0; 5 > i; i++) {
     $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
    }
  }
}

// При наведении
$('.stars .star').hover(function() {
 var NowPos = $(this);
 cStars(NowPos);
});

// При клике
$('.stars .star').click(function() {
 var NowPos = $(this);
 cStars(NowPos);
});
```

```css
.stars {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.star {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.star.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В код добавляется переменная, которая хранит в себе количество активных элементов. Она обновляется при клике, а при потере фокуса вызывается функция, которая заново перекрашивает все элементы до нужного значения.

```js
var cStars = function(nowPos) {
  // У всех убираем active
  $('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
  for (var i = 0; nowPos + 1 > i; i++) {
    $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
  }
}

//переменная содержит количество активных звезд
var starsCount = $('.star.active').length;

// При наведении
$('.stars .star').hover(function() {
  cStars($(this).index());
});

// При клике
$('.stars .star').click(function() {
  cStars($(this).index());
  //меняем количество по клику
  starsCount = $('.star.active').length;
});

$('.stars .star').on('mouseleave', function() {
  cStars(+starsCount - 1);
});
```

```css
.stars {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.star {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.star.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars">
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star active"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
  <span class="star"></span>
</div>
```

P.S.

1. Переменную `NowPos` лучше переименовать в `nowPos` - общепринятое написание имени переменных для языка JS
2. Лучше в переменную `nowPos` передавать не объект, а индекс, так как используется только он, и название переменной подразумевает номер позиции.

Answer (score 2):

Ну если сократить код то получится так:

```
var cStars = function(NowPos) {
$('.stars .star').removeClass('active');
for(var i = 0; NowPos.index()+1 > i; i++)
    $('.stars .star').eq(i).toggleClass('active');
}

// При наведении
$('.stars .star').hover(function() {
var NowPos = $(this);
cStars(NowPos);
});

// При клике
$('.stars .star').click(function() {
var NowPos = $(this);
cStars(NowPos);
});
```

Comment: Эх, как же я упустил) А что насчет решения бага?)

Comment: У тебя события наведения и клика одинаковые, поэтому надо логику переписывать. Я не пишу на js но если есть событие когда уводишь курсор, то возвращать значение.

Comment: Sergey Glazirin исправил баг)

Answer (score 0):

Тут даже javascript не нужен - вот пример

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1066077/308951)

```css
.rating {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label {
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★';
}

.rating>input:checked~label {
  color: gold;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: gold;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">

  <input type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1">
  <label for="star-1" title="Оценка «1»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
  <label for="star-2" title="Оценка «2»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
  <label for="star-3" title="Оценка «3»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
  <label for="star-4" title="Оценка «4»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="star-5" title="Оценка «5»"></label>

</div>
```