# Вёрстка "звёздного" рейтинга

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка, svg

Думаю многие сталкивались, на различных сайтах, с возможностью оценить что-либо.
Где-то это лайки (like), где-то "рейтинг", обычно в виде звёздочек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предо мной встал вопрос, какие способы есть для вёрстки именно "голосования", т.е. выбора оценки, допустим до пяти балов.

Как-то я делал вот такой вариант:

```js
$('.rating .star').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.rating').find('.--selected').removeClass('--selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('--selected');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css');
:root {
  --star-size: 14px;
}

.rating {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc((var(--star-size) * 5) + 20px);
  height: var(--star-size);
  margin-right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  font-size: 0;
}

.rating .star {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: var(--star-size);
  height: var(--star-size);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-moothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  font-weight: 900;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.rating .star:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.rating .star::before {
  content: '\f005';
  display: block;
  width: var(--star-size);
  height: var(--star-size);
  line-height: var(--star-size);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--star-size);
  font-weight: 400;
}

.rating .star.--selected,
.rating .star.--selected ~ .star,
.rating .star:hover,
.rating .star:hover ~ .star {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rating">
  <span class="star" data-rating="5"></span>
  <span class="star" data-rating="4"></span>
  <span class="star" data-rating="3"></span>
  <span class="star" data-rating="2"></span>
  <span class="star" data-rating="1"></span>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы увидеть какие ещё есть варианты реализации.
Приветствуется всё: js\jq, svg, и т.д.

**Особенности:**
Возможность получения оценки (чтобы в дальнейшем можно было обработать).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbajTYI-gg8 - звездный рейтинг от В.Макеева

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот например такая реализация, все на svg:

```js
class Rating {
  constructor(dom) {
    dom.innerHTML = '<svg width="110" height="20"></svg>';
    this.svg = dom.querySelector('svg');
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      this.svg.innerHTML += `<polygon data-value="${i+1}"
           transform="translate(${i*22},0)" 
           points="10,1 4,19.8 19,7.8 1,7.8 16,19.8">`;
    this.svg.onclick = e => this.change(e);
    this.render();
  }
  
  change(e) {
    let value = e.target.dataset.value;
    value && (this.svg.parentNode.dataset.value = value); 
    this.render();
  }
  
  render() {
    this.svg.querySelectorAll('polygon').forEach(star => {
      let on = +this.svg.parentNode.dataset.value >= +star.dataset.value;
      star.classList.toggle('active', on);
    });
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.rating').forEach(dom => new Rating(dom));
```

```css
.rating polygon:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.rating polygon:hover {
  fill: black;
}
.rating polygon {
  fill: lightgray;
}
.rating polygon.active{
  fill: gold;
}
```

```html
<span class="rating"></span>
<span class="rating" data-value="1"></span>
<div class="rating" data-value="3"></div>
<div class="rating" data-value="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если можно использовать плагины то есть такой отличный вариант.Достал из архива :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question1').on('rating.change',(event, value) => console.log(value));
  $('#question1').on('rating.clear', e => console.log("rating:clear"));
});
```

```css
.rating-loading {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
/*
 * Stars
 */
.rating-gly {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

.rating-gly-star {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.rating-lg .rating-gly-star,
.rating-lg .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 4px;
}
.rating-xl .rating-gly-star,
.rating-xl .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-active {
  cursor: default;
}

.rating-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-uni {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.rating-container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}

.rating-container .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.rating-container-rtl:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}


/**
 * Rating sizes
 */

.rating-xl {
  font-size: 4.89em;
}

.rating-lg {
  font-size: 3.91em;
}

.rating-md {
  font-size: 3.13em;
}

.rating-sm {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.rating-xs {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/**
 * Clear rating button
 */

.star-rating .clear-rating,
.star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 60%;
}

.clear-rating-active {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.clear-rating-active:hover {
  color: #843534;
}

.star-rating .clear-rating {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/**
 * Caption
 */

.star-rating .caption,
.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 55%;
}

.star-rating .caption {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>

<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
</form>
```

Comment: Вроде все с ним окей, кроме того что в лог 0 не пишется

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да спасибо ша гляну

Comment: @StrangerintheQ исправил.

Comment: ну и отлично, второй плюс не поставлю, сори =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ огромное спасибо и за первый :)

Comment: этот пример работает в ie11 а все остальные нет

Comment: @MaximLensky ниже ie11 не работает?

Comment: наоборот - твой пример работает а все остальные нет

Comment: @MaximLensky и не должны были =), в ie нету стрелочных функций и шаблонов строк

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я думаю никому не составит труда проста перевести твой код через babel. Поэтому считаю что кроссбраузерность не помеха.

Comment: @MaximLensky я не расстроился, просто тоже хочу поучаствовать в беседе )

Answer (score 3):

Тоже свои пять копеек вставлю но без js

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}

.star-ratio {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.ratio {
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYO64.png);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.star-ratio:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 2em;
  z-index: 5;
}

.star-ratio:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 4em;
  z-index: 4;
}

.star-ratio:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 6em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.star-ratio:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 8em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.star-ratio:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: 10em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.star-ratio:checked,
.star-ratio:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV18m.png);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.star-ratio:hover~.star-ratio {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYO64.png);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
  <input type="radio" class="star-ratio" name="rt">
  <input type="radio" class="star-ratio" name="rt">
  <input type="radio" class="star-ratio" name="rt">
  <input type="radio" class="star-ratio" name="rt">
  <input type="radio" class="star-ratio" name="rt">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант, логика на input+css, svg картинка [заинлайнена](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) в css

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.rating').forEach(dom => {
  let id = 'rating_' + dom.dataset.name;
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    dom.innerHTML += `
      <label for=${id}_${i}></label>
      <input type=radio ${dom.dataset.value-1===i&&'checked'||''} 
             name=${id} 
             id=${id}_${i} 
             onclick="ratingChanged('${dom.dataset.name}', ${i+1})">`;
});

function ratingChanged(id, value){
  console.log(id, value);
}
```

```css
.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' \
    width='20' height='20'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='gold' \
    points='10,1,4,19.8, 19,7.8,1,7.8,16,19.8'%3E%3C/polygon%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 500ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating input:checked ~ label{
   filter:grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<span class="rating" data-name="parameter1"></span>
<span class="rating" data-value="1" data-name="parameter2"></span>
<div class="rating" data-value="3" data-name="parameter3"></div>
<div class="rating" data-value="5" data-name="parameter4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не давно на [toster](https://qna.habr.com/q/698063) был подобный вопрос и я чуть чуть перепилил [свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017051/308951) без картинки

```css
.rating {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label {
  width: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★';
}

.rating>input:checked~label {
  color: gold;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: gold;
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">

  <input type="radio" id="star-1" name="rating" value="1">
  <label for="star-1" title="Оценка «1»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-2" name="rating" value="2">
  <label for="star-2" title="Оценка «2»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-3" name="rating" value="3">
  <label for="star-3" title="Оценка «3»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-4" name="rating" value="4">
  <label for="star-4" title="Оценка «4»"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="star-5" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="star-5" title="Оценка «5»"></label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const starRaiting = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-star");

function handleActiveStar(event) {
  let star = this;
  let parent = star.parentNode;
  parent.dataset.value = 0;
  for (const child of parent.children) {
    child.classList.add('fa-regular');
    child.classList.remove('fa-solid');
  }
  while (star) {
    parent.dataset.value++;
    star.classList.remove('fa-regular');
    star.classList.add('fa-solid');
    star = star.previousElementSibling;
  }
  return;
}

starRaiting.forEach(star => {
  star.addEventListener("click", handleActiveStar);
});
```

```css
.fa-solid {
  color: rgb(255, 212, 22);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ddb9b22630.js"></script>
<div class="raiting" data-value="">
  <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Лайк за старание, но сейчас это совсем не актуально :)